# Complex figure with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create the following picture with tikz [image]

I have found this block of code, which outputs a similar result of what I want to get:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows ,calc}

\tikzset{
    modal/.style={>=stealth’,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt,auto,node distance=1.5cm,
        semithick},
    world/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=0.5cm,fill=gray!15},
    point/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=0.5mm,fill=black},
    reflexive above/.style={->,loop,looseness=7,in=120,out=60},
    reflexive below/.style={->,loop,looseness=7,in=240,out=300},
    reflexive left/.style={->,loop,looseness=7,in=150,out=210},
    reflexive right/.style={->,loop,looseness=7,in=30,out=330}
}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[modal,node distance=4cm]
\node (A) {A};
\node (E) [right=of A] {E};
\node (I) [below=of A] {I};
\node (O) [below=of E] {O};
\coordinate (CENTER) at ($(A)!0.5!(O)$);
\node (contra) at (CENTER) {contradictory};
\path[<->] (A) edge node[above] {contrary} (E);
\path[<->] (I) edge node[below] {subcontrary} (O);
\path[->] (A) edge node[above,rotate=90] {subaltern} (I);
\path[->] (E) edge node[above,rotate=-90] {subaltern} (O);
\path[->] (contra) edge (A);
\path[->] (contra) edge (E);
\path[->] (contra) edge (I);
\path[->] (contra) edge (O);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to add some text near the nodes, without changing the pointing of the arrows.

Furthermore, I get this error:  Package pgf Error: Unknown arrow tip kind 'stealth’'.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. it will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Your code isen't compilable, so we can't see your result (still now).

Comment: Related to your node problem: [Position text next to rectangle in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75301/124842). So you can use for example `\node[label=east:text] (E) [right=of A] {E};` and `\node[label=west:text] (I) [below=of A] {I};`

Comment: I have updated the post. But I get some errors when compiling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint to your code: Use `>=stealth'` instead of `>=stealth’` to achive a minimal working example.

You can use:

- `shorten >=0.1cm` or `shorten <=0.1cm` to short the arrow on both ends with a defined length (for example `0.1` here)
- `label=west:your text` for labeling (`your text`) the nodes in different orientation (`west`, `east`,...)
- `\node[left=0cm and 0cm of A,` node position relative to `A`
- some more coordinates like `\coordinate (EAST) at ($(E)!0.5!(O)$);`
  or `\coordinate (SOUTH) at ($(I)!0.5!(O)$);` to place the text near the nodes
- path color, just `\path[blue,->]`...
  [image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,calc}
\tikzset{
modal/.style={>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt,auto,node distance=1.5cm,
semithick},
world/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=0.5cm,fill=gray!15},
point/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=0.5mm,fill=black},
reflexive above/.style={->,loop,looseness=7,in=120,out=60},
reflexive below/.style={->,loop,looseness=7,in=240,out=300},
reflexive left/.style={->,loop,looseness=7,in=150,out=210},
reflexive right/.style={->,loop,looseness=7,in=30,out=330}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[modal,node distance=4cm]
\node(A) {A};
\node(E) [right=of A] {E};
\node(I) [below=of A] {I};
\node(O) [below=of E] {O};
\coordinate (CENTER) at ($(A)!0.5!(O)$);
\coordinate (NORTH) at ($(A)!0.5!(E)$);
\coordinate (WEST) at ($(A)!0.5!(I)$);
\coordinate (EAST) at ($(E)!0.5!(O)$);
\coordinate (SOUTH) at ($(I)!0.5!(O)$);
\node (contra) at (CENTER) {text};
\path[blue,->] (A) edge node[left,rotate=0] {} (I);%90
\path[->] (E) edge node[right,rotate=0] {} (O);%-90
\path[shorten <=0.2cm,->] (contra) edge (A);
\path[shorten <=0.2cm,->] (contra) edge (E);
\path[shorten <=0.2cm,->] (contra) edge (I);
\path[shorten <=0.2cm,->] (contra) edge (O);
\path[shorten >=0.5cm,shorten <=0.5cm,->] (contra) edge (EAST);
\path[shorten >=0.5cm,shorten <=0.5cm,->] (contra) edge (WEST);
%
\node (contra) at (NORTH) {text};
\node (pro) at (SOUTH) {text};
%
\path[shorten >=0.3cm,shorten <=0.5cm,->] (contra) edge (E);
\path[shorten >=0.3cm,shorten <=0.5cm,->] (contra) edge (A);
%
\path[->] (pro) edge (I);
\path[->] (pro) edge (O);
%
\node[left=0cm and 0cm of A, label=west:text] {(1)};
\node[left=0cm and 0cm of I, label=west:text] {(1)};
\node[left=0cm and 0cm of WEST, label=west:text] {(0.5)};
\node[right=0cm and 0cm of E, label=east:text] {(1)};
\node[right=0cm and 0cm of O, label=east:text] {(1)};
\node[right=0cm and 0cm of EAST, label=east:text] {(-0.5)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```