# How to draw an equilateral triangle with text on the edges (corners) using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a triangle with text on the edges (corners) as shown in the image.

The MWE [modified from [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88638/equilateral-triangle-in-tikz#:%7E:text=You%20can%20just%20set%20isosceles,to%20get%20an%20equilateral%20triangle.)] is:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{
    buffer/.style={
        draw,
        shape border rotate=90,
        isosceles triangle,
        isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
        node distance=2cm,
        minimum height=2em
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[buffer]{Text};
\draw node[above]{Text};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add that code to your question. Thank you

Comment: I have added MWE. I have tried to merge the above with this solution [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13539/label-sides-of-rectangles-and-triangles].

Comment: You have several options to continue. Look e.g. for anchor in the manual, and polar coordinates.

Comment: You can just draw that triangle without a shape and place nodes at the corners: `\draw[align=center] (0,0) node[left]{x} --+(right:4) node[right]{y} --+(60:4) node[above]{z} --cycle;` You just need to fill the node with content.

Comment: Alternatively, name the triangle node and use it's anchors for placing the three text nodes. Possibly, you can even use the `label` key but it makes the input a bit weird.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have two solutions. One places text nodes after the triangle and second uses three labels to place the text.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning}

\tikzset{
    buffer/.style={
        draw,
        shape border rotate=90,
        isosceles triangle,
        isosceles triangle apex angle=60,
        node distance=2cm,
        minimum height=2em
    },
    textblock/.style={text width=2cm, inner sep=0pt, align=#1},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[buffer] (a) {Text.in};
\node[textblock=center, above= 1mm of a]{Some text text text text text text};
\node[textblock=left, above right= 0mm and 0mm of a.right corner]{Right text text text text text text text};
\node[textblock=right, above left= 0mm and 0mm of a.left corner]{Left text text text text text text text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[buffer, label={[textblock=center]above:Above text text},
label={[textblock=left, anchor=south west]right corner:Right text text},
label={[textblock=right, anchor=south east]left corner:Left text text},
] (a) {Text.in};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]