# Drawing Mass Spring Damp Systems in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to draw a Spring-Mass-Damping system by TikZ. I found the example in [Drawing Mechanical Systems in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13933/drawing-mechanical-systems-in-latex/13952#13952)

But I have problems compiling it. If I delete the damper code
`\draw [dampener] (ground2.north) -- ($(M.south east)!(ground2.north)!(M.south west)$)` 
it works well

The error message as below:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/mark connection node' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.30 \draw [dampener]
                      (ground2.north) -- ($(M.south east)!(ground2.north)!(M...

? 
[1
```

As I can't reply to the original question, I have to posted a new question about this issue.

Comment: I wonder if this is a version issue. What version of `pgf` do you have installed?

Comment: version information as below:

`(d:\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\libraries\tikzlibrarytopaths
.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v2.00-cvs (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
PGFVersion=2.00-cvs
 )`

Comment: There is no problem with my system with Miktex 2.9/pgf-TikZ 2.10

Comment: @laplace: Can you remove everything from your document except for this `tikzpicture`, and post the code in the question please?

Comment: Thanks all for your quickly and effective answers. I uninstall the tex system, and re-install a latest distribution revision. Then solved the issue. Although I'm not sure what cause of it. Maybe the  old revision of Miktex program.

Comment: Can anyone else reproduce this problem? If not then perhaps we should close this question.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfect for me. Did you forget to add TikZ libraries?

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.markings}
```

Comment: Fernando, thanks for you answer. I have copy the whole codes, also contains `\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}`