# text above arrow in question "drawing-mechanical-systems-in-latex"?

Tags: tikz-pgf

With reference to the first answer in this: [Drawing Mechanical Systems in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13933/drawing-mechanical-systems-in-latex)

I want the text `x` above the arrow, simple as that, also how can I control how high above the arrow it is?

So I tried adding an `{$x$}` to the "-latex" arrow, like this:

```
\draw [-latex,ultra thick] (M.east) ++ (0.2cm,0) -- +(1cm,0) node [midway,above] {$x$};
```

but the `x` gets boxed, I want it without the box.

Maybe one could show me how to cancel for node style that was set in the beginning, but that would remove the box around `m` which is important.

Comment: Use `node [draw=none,midway,above] {$x$};`.

Comment: Use `node [draw=none,midway,above=3cm] {$x$};`. Change `3cm` to whatever you desire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the options for `draw` (`draw=none)` and `above` (`above=1ex)` in

```
node [draw=none,midway,above=3cm] {$x$};
```

Hence you have to add

```
\draw [-latex,ultra thick] (M.east) ++ (0.2cm,0) -- +(1cm,0) node [draw=none,midway,above=3cm] {$x$};
```

to get rid of the box and control the distance of `x` from arrow.

Comment: thank you so much, you helped me in no time, this is great!

Comment: @user18601: If this answer solved your problem, you may consider upvoting  and also accepting (by clicking the check mark below vote count) it. This is how we say thanks here in TeX.SX.