# How to shade a line and how to offset a line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

Newbie here. Could anyone tell me how to (1) shade a line and (2) how to offset a line?

I have a very simple graph,[image]

This is a mesh used in finite element analysis, I have already used tikz to build a mesh and I am satisfied with it. But now I want to improve it! The shade effect represents it is a "fixed wall", and the second layer grid line should be offset of the first wall layer line.

Here is my scripts of generating the grids. (You dont need to follow this scripts. You can disregard this scripts, a two layer grid lines is enough for me.)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    scale=1,
    every node/.style={scale=0.5},
    x=0.1cm,y=0.1cm
]
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}


\draw ( 0.0, 0.0)--( 8.0, 0.0)--(16.0, 0.0)--(22.0, 3.0)--(26.5, 6.5)--(30.0,14.5)--(33.0,16.2)--(36.0,14.5)--(39.5, 6.5)--(44.0, 3.0)--(50.0, 0.0)--(58.0, 0.0)--(66.0, 0.0);
\draw (0.0,8.5)--(8.0,8.8)--(14.2,9.1)--(17.9,10.0)--(22.5,12.0)--(27.6,17.6)--(32.2,19.7)--(38.4,17.6)--(43.5,12.0)--(48.1,10.0)--(51.8, 9.1)--(58.0, 8.8)--(66.0,8.5);
\draw (0.0,17.3)--(6.2,18.5)--(11.2,18.8)--(14.6,19.0)--(21.9,19.9)--(28.4,22.5)--(35.0,25.0)--(37.6,22.5)--(44.1,19.9)--(51.4,19.0)--(54.8,18.8)--(59.8,18.5)--(66.0,17.3);
\draw (0.0,30.0)--(6.2,30.0)--(11.2,30.0)--(14.6,30.0)--(21.9,30.0)--(28.4,30.0)--(35.0,30.0)--(37.6,30.0)--(44.1,30.0)--(51.4,30.0)--(54.8,30.0)--(59.8,30.0)--(66.0,30.0);
\draw ( 0.0, 0.0)--( 0.0, 8.5)--( 0.0,17.3)--( 0.0,30.0);
\draw ( 8.0, 0.0)--( 8.0, 8.8)--( 6.2,18.5)--( 6.2,30.0);
\draw (16.0, 0.0)--(14.2, 9.1)--(11.2,18.8)--(11.2,30.0);
\draw (22.0, 3.0)--(17.9,10.0)--(14.6,19.0)--(14.6,30.0);
\draw (26.5, 6.5)--(22.5,12.0)--(21.9,19.9)--(21.9,30.0);
\draw (30.0,14.5)--(27.6,17.6)--(28.4,22.5)--(28.4,30.0);
\draw (33.0,16.2)--(32.2,19.7)--(35.0,25.0)--(35.0,30.0);
\draw (36.0,14.5)--(38.4,17.6)--(37.6,22.5)--(37.6,30.0);
\draw (39.5, 6.5)--(43.5,12.0)--(44.1,19.9)--(44.1,30.0);
\draw (44.0, 3.0)--(48.1,10.0)--(51.4,19.0)--(51.4,30.0);
\draw (50.0, 0.0)--(51.8, 9.1)--(54.8,18.8)--(54.8,30.0);
\draw (58.0, 0.0)--(58.0, 8.8)--(59.8,18.5)--(59.8,30.0);
\draw (66.0, 0.0)--(66.0, 8.5)--(66.0,17.3)--(66.0,30.0);



\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: For the shaded line: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13933/drawing-mechanical-systems-in-latex

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With clipping:

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mypath}{(0.0,0.0) -- ( 8.0, 0.0) -- (16.0, 0.0) -- (22.0, 3.0) -- (26.5,6.5) -- (30.0,14.5) -- (33.0,16.2) -- (36.0,14.5) -- (39.5,6.5) -- (44.0,3.0) -- (50.0,0.0) -- (58.0,0.0) -- (66.0, 0.0)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   scale=0.1,
]
    \draw \mypath;
    \draw (0.0,8.5) -- (8.0,8.8) -- (14.2,9.1) -- (17.9,10.0) -- (22.5,12.0) -- (27.6,17.6) -- (32.2,19.7) -- (38.4,17.6) -- (43.5,12.0) -- (48.1,10.0) -- (51.8, 9.1) -- (58.0, 8.8) -- (66.0,8.5);
    \draw (0.0,17.3) -- (6.2,18.5) -- (11.2,18.8) -- (14.6,19.0) -- (21.9,19.9) -- (28.4,22.5) -- (35.0,25.0) -- (37.6,22.5) -- (44.1,19.9) -- (51.4,19.0) -- (54.8,18.8) -- (59.8,18.5) -- (66.0,17.3);
    \draw (0.0,30.0) -- (6.2,30.0) -- (11.2,30.0) -- (14.6,30.0) -- (21.9,30.0) -- (28.4,30.0) -- (35.0,30.0) -- (37.6,30.0) -- (44.1,30.0) -- (51.4,30.0) -- (54.8,30.0) -- (59.8,30.0) -- (66.0,30.0);
    \draw ( 0.0, 0.0) -- ( 0.0, 8.5) -- ( 0.0,17.3) -- ( 0.0,30.0);
    \draw ( 8.0, 0.0) -- ( 8.0, 8.8) -- ( 6.2,18.5) -- ( 6.2,30.0);
    \draw (16.0, 0.0) -- (14.2, 9.1) -- (11.2,18.8) -- (11.2,30.0);
    \draw (22.0, 3.0) -- (17.9,10.0) -- (14.6,19.0) -- (14.6,30.0);
    \draw (26.5, 6.5) -- (22.5,12.0) -- (21.9,19.9) -- (21.9,30.0);
    \draw (30.0,14.5) -- (27.6,17.6) -- (28.4,22.5) -- (28.4,30.0);
    \draw (33.0,16.2) -- (32.2,19.7) -- (35.0,25.0) -- (35.0,30.0);
    \draw (36.0,14.5) -- (38.4,17.6) -- (37.6,22.5) -- (37.6,30.0);
    \draw (39.5, 6.5) -- (43.5,12.0) -- (44.1,19.9) -- (44.1,30.0);
    \draw (44.0, 3.0) -- (48.1,10.0) -- (51.4,19.0) -- (51.4,30.0);
    \draw (50.0, 0.0) -- (51.8, 9.1) -- (54.8,18.8) -- (54.8,30.0);
    \draw (58.0, 0.0) -- (58.0, 8.8) -- (59.8,18.5) -- (59.8,30.0);
    \draw (66.0, 0.0) -- (66.0, 8.5) -- (66.0,17.3) -- (66.0,30.0);
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \mypath |- (0,-2) -- cycle;
        \draw[line width=1mm,densely dotted] \mypath;
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

With decoration:

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mypath}{(0.0,0.0) -- ( 8.0, 0.0) -- (16.0, 0.0) -- (22.0, 3.0) -- (26.5,6.5) -- (30.0,14.5) -- (33.0,16.2) -- (36.0,14.5) -- (39.5,6.5) -- (44.0,3.0) -- (50.0,0.0) -- (58.0,0.0) -- (66.0, 0.0)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   scale=0.1,
]
    \draw \mypath;
    \draw (0.0,8.5) -- (8.0,8.8) -- (14.2,9.1) -- (17.9,10.0) -- (22.5,12.0) -- (27.6,17.6) -- (32.2,19.7) -- (38.4,17.6) -- (43.5,12.0) -- (48.1,10.0) -- (51.8, 9.1) -- (58.0, 8.8) -- (66.0,8.5);
    \draw (0.0,17.3) -- (6.2,18.5) -- (11.2,18.8) -- (14.6,19.0) -- (21.9,19.9) -- (28.4,22.5) -- (35.0,25.0) -- (37.6,22.5) -- (44.1,19.9) -- (51.4,19.0) -- (54.8,18.8) -- (59.8,18.5) -- (66.0,17.3);
    \draw (0.0,30.0) -- (6.2,30.0) -- (11.2,30.0) -- (14.6,30.0) -- (21.9,30.0) -- (28.4,30.0) -- (35.0,30.0) -- (37.6,30.0) -- (44.1,30.0) -- (51.4,30.0) -- (54.8,30.0) -- (59.8,30.0) -- (66.0,30.0);
    \draw ( 0.0, 0.0) -- ( 0.0, 8.5) -- ( 0.0,17.3) -- ( 0.0,30.0);
    \draw ( 8.0, 0.0) -- ( 8.0, 8.8) -- ( 6.2,18.5) -- ( 6.2,30.0);
    \draw (16.0, 0.0) -- (14.2, 9.1) -- (11.2,18.8) -- (11.2,30.0);
    \draw (22.0, 3.0) -- (17.9,10.0) -- (14.6,19.0) -- (14.6,30.0);
    \draw (26.5, 6.5) -- (22.5,12.0) -- (21.9,19.9) -- (21.9,30.0);
    \draw (30.0,14.5) -- (27.6,17.6) -- (28.4,22.5) -- (28.4,30.0);
    \draw (33.0,16.2) -- (32.2,19.7) -- (35.0,25.0) -- (35.0,30.0);
    \draw (36.0,14.5) -- (38.4,17.6) -- (37.6,22.5) -- (37.6,30.0);
    \draw (39.5, 6.5) -- (43.5,12.0) -- (44.1,19.9) -- (44.1,30.0);
    \draw (44.0, 3.0) -- (48.1,10.0) -- (51.4,19.0) -- (51.4,30.0);
    \draw (50.0, 0.0) -- (51.8, 9.1) -- (54.8,18.8) -- (54.8,30.0);
    \draw (58.0, 0.0) -- (58.0, 8.8) -- (59.8,18.5) -- (59.8,30.0);
    \draw (66.0, 0.0) -- (66.0, 8.5) -- (66.0,17.3) -- (66.0,30.0);
    \draw[decoration={ticks,segment length=0.25mm,amplitude=0.3mm,raise=-0.25mm},decorate] \mypath;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

With inclinded lines:

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mypath}{(0.0,0.0) -- ( 8.0, 0.0) -- (16.0, 0.0) -- (22.0, 3.0) -- (26.5,6.5) -- (30.0,14.5) -- (33.0,16.2) -- (36.0,14.5) -- (39.5,6.5) -- (44.0,3.0) -- (50.0,0.0) -- (58.0,0.0) -- (66.0, 0.0)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   scale=0.1,
]
    \draw \mypath;
    \draw (0.0,8.5) -- (8.0,8.8) -- (14.2,9.1) -- (17.9,10.0) -- (22.5,12.0) -- (27.6,17.6) -- (32.2,19.7) -- (38.4,17.6) -- (43.5,12.0) -- (48.1,10.0) -- (51.8, 9.1) -- (58.0, 8.8) -- (66.0,8.5);
    \draw (0.0,17.3) -- (6.2,18.5) -- (11.2,18.8) -- (14.6,19.0) -- (21.9,19.9) -- (28.4,22.5) -- (35.0,25.0) -- (37.6,22.5) -- (44.1,19.9) -- (51.4,19.0) -- (54.8,18.8) -- (59.8,18.5) -- (66.0,17.3);
    \draw (0.0,30.0) -- (6.2,30.0) -- (11.2,30.0) -- (14.6,30.0) -- (21.9,30.0) -- (28.4,30.0) -- (35.0,30.0) -- (37.6,30.0) -- (44.1,30.0) -- (51.4,30.0) -- (54.8,30.0) -- (59.8,30.0) -- (66.0,30.0);
    \draw ( 0.0, 0.0) -- ( 0.0, 8.5) -- ( 0.0,17.3) -- ( 0.0,30.0);
    \draw ( 8.0, 0.0) -- ( 8.0, 8.8) -- ( 6.2,18.5) -- ( 6.2,30.0);
    \draw (16.0, 0.0) -- (14.2, 9.1) -- (11.2,18.8) -- (11.2,30.0);
    \draw (22.0, 3.0) -- (17.9,10.0) -- (14.6,19.0) -- (14.6,30.0);
    \draw (26.5, 6.5) -- (22.5,12.0) -- (21.9,19.9) -- (21.9,30.0);
    \draw (30.0,14.5) -- (27.6,17.6) -- (28.4,22.5) -- (28.4,30.0);
    \draw (33.0,16.2) -- (32.2,19.7) -- (35.0,25.0) -- (35.0,30.0);
    \draw (36.0,14.5) -- (38.4,17.6) -- (37.6,22.5) -- (37.6,30.0);
    \draw (39.5, 6.5) -- (43.5,12.0) -- (44.1,19.9) -- (44.1,30.0);
    \draw (44.0, 3.0) -- (48.1,10.0) -- (51.4,19.0) -- (51.4,30.0);
    \draw (50.0, 0.0) -- (51.8, 9.1) -- (54.8,18.8) -- (54.8,30.0);
    \draw (58.0, 0.0) -- (58.0, 8.8) -- (59.8,18.5) -- (59.8,30.0);
    \draw (66.0, 0.0) -- (66.0, 8.5) -- (66.0,17.3) -- (66.0,30.0);
    \draw[decoration={border,segment length=0.3mm,amplitude=0.8mm,mirror,angle=45},decorate] \mypath;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Couldn't the decoration lines be inclined?

Comment: Yes, just add `angle=<degrees>` to the decoration.

Comment: You mean this `\draw[decoration={ticks,segment length=0.5mm,amplitude=0.9mm,raise=-1mm,angle=50},decorate] \mypath;`? Nothing happens...

Comment: You'll need the `border` decoration instead of the `ticks` decoration, see the last update.