# How to make curved springs (coils) in tikz, for a mechanics problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Is there anyway using say tikz (preferred, or pstricks would be OK too) to make curved coils? Essentially I want to make beads on a circular wire that are joined by springs. Here are the images I would like to make:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/lh6Ze9I.jpg]

A regular coils has small non-coiled segments near the ends of the springs, while the images above do not have such segments. However, I would like to have small straight segments near the ends of the springs if possible.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Sorry, this is is my first post and to search on how to make springs I looked at the page http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13933/drawing-mechanical-systems-in-latex. That page only put a picture (and not compilable document), so I assumed it was standard practice to put pictures only with no code. I apologize. I should have asked before. This will not happen again.

Answer (score 7):

Your  question is one among set of "do-it-for-me" ...

**Edit:** anyway, @AboAmmar was faster few seconds with the almost the same solution. So In dilema what to do, I first erase my answer, then activate, again erase and on the end, decide due to small diferences activate it.

[image]

Above picture is drawn by:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz,
               ]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    decoration={coil,amplitude=3mm,segment length=3mm}
                    ]
\draw                       (0,0)   circle  (2);
\draw[decorate,thick,red]   ( 95:2) arc     ( 95:270:2);
\draw[decorate,thick,blue]  (-85:2) arc     (-85:90:2);
\fill[black]                (0,-2)  circle  (3mm)
                            (0, 2)  circle (3mm);
\draw[thick,<->]            (70:2.6) arc    (70:110:2.6) node[above,midway] {$F_d(t)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I think your solution handles the joins to the beads more effectively.

Comment: @Thruston, to be honest, in first I try (unfortunately unsuccessful in short time) to find link between coil amplitude, segment length and circle diameter, so I decide to split circle into two arc, which are easy to manipulate. Ones I will try to derive math expression for this (in spare time) ...

Answer (score 5):

Try this `decoration` method:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

\scriptsize
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\draw[decorate,decoration={coil,segment length=4pt},rotate=92] (0,0) circle(1cm);
\draw[fill] (0,1) node[above=.2cm]{$F_d(t)$} circle(3pt) (0,-1) circle(3pt);
\draw [<->] (75:1.2cm) arc [radius=1.2cm, start angle=75, end angle=105];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]