# horizontal multiple oscillators

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am sorry for the previous problem, I am a beginner of this forum.

I have written the following code, in order to draw 2 coupled horizontal oscillators with dampers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0pt,thick}]
\tikzstyle{spring}=[thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment length=6}]
\tikzstyle{damper}=[thick,decoration={markings,
  mark connection node=dmp,
  mark=at position 0.5 with
  {
    \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=10pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$);
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-3pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,3pt)$);
  }
}, decorate]
\tikzstyle{ground}=[fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.3cm]

\begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
\node (M) [minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] {$m$} node[draw=none,fill=none,pos=.5,below] {1};

\draw [<-,thick](-2.6,.6) -- (-1.5,-.2);

\node (wall) [ground, rotate=-90, minimum width=2cm,yshift=-3cm] {};

\draw (wall.north east) -- (wall.north west);

\draw [spring] (wall.120) -- ($(M.north west)!(wall.120)!(M.south west)$) node[draw=none,fill=none,pos=.5,above] {$k_1$};

\draw [damper] (wall.20) -- ($(M.north west)!(wall.20)!(M.south west)$) node[draw=none,fill=none,pos=.5,below] {$d_1$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=10cm]
\node (M1) [minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm] {$m$} node[draw=none,fill=none,pos=.5,below] {2};

\draw [spring] (M.10) -- ($(M1.north west)!(M.10)!(M1.south west)$) node[draw=none,fill=none,pos=.5,above] {$K$};

\draw [damper] (M.-40) -- ($(M1.north west)!(M.-40)!(M1.south west)$);

\draw [->,thick](1.4,-.2) -- (2.5,.6);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=10cm]
\node (wall1) [ground, rotate=90, minimum width=2cm,yshift=-3cm] {};

\draw (wall1.north west) -- (wall1.north east);

\draw [spring] (wall1.60) -- ($(M1.north east)!(wall1.60)!(M1.south east)$) node[draw=none,fill=none,pos=.5,above] {$k_2$};

\draw [damper] (wall1.-160) -- ($(M1.north east)!(wall1.-160)!(M1.south east)$) node[draw=none,fill=none,pos=.5,below] {$d_2$};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would need help to fix the following issues:

1. The notations "d_1" and "d_2" of the two dampers should be placed with about 3mm, under the dampers.
2. The notations "1" and "2" of the two blocks should be placed under the rectangles and not at the interior.
3. The right-side point of the second damper should start from the vertical rule of the right wall, not from those north east lines.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Have a look at [Drawing Mechanical Systems in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13952/124842) or [Parallel elements when drawing a vertical mechanical diagram with Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361634/124842)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  wall/.style = {gray,fill=gray},
  mass/.style = {draw,circle,ball color=red},
  spring/.style = {decorate,decoration={zigzag, pre length=.3cm,post length=.3cm,segment length=#1}},
  ]
  \draw[wall] (-.5,-1) rectangle (0,1);
  \coordinate (l) at (0,0);
  \node[mass,label={above:$m_1$}] (m1) at (3,0) {};
  \node[mass,label={above:$m_2$}] (m2) at (5,0) {};
  \coordinate (r) at (6,0);
  \draw[wall] (6,-1) rectangle (6.5,1);

  \draw[spring=8pt] (l) -- node[above] {$k_1$} (m1);
  \draw[spring=4pt] (m1) -- node[above] {$K$} (m2);
  \draw[spring=2pt] (m2) -- node[above] {$k_2$} (r);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]