# How can I draw a diagram of forces figure like following?

Tags: diagrams, technical-drawing

I want to draw figure as following pic for LATEX. Which program do you suggest me to draw like the following figure?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  What have you tried so far?  Questions that take on the guise of "do this for me" are generally not well received by the community.

Comment: Yes you can. With TikZ for instance. But that's a lot of work to request. You should ask (or search because it's probably asked before) how to do what you have doubts about, and then put everything together to get the figure. You can search about drawing arrows, drawing a mesh, how to make a “random” line as a function, how to do circles, etc. Most of it is easy after reading a few pages of TikZ manual, and you can do it yourself.

Comment: In general, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26972/586 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/597/586

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13933/drawing-mechanical-systems-in-latex and http://latex-community.org/know-how/latex/50-latex-graphics-figures-tables/472-tikz-structural-analysis

Comment: see pst-stru: http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-stru/doc/pst-stru-doc.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Tikz for that matter. This is a simple approach for drawing your diagram. The result is

[image]

and this is the code for the preceding image.

```
\documentclass[border={10pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}



\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{MYcrosshatch}{\pgfqpoint{-2pt}{-2pt}}{\pgfqpoint{8pt}{8pt}}{\pgfqpoint{7.5pt}{7.5pt}}%
{
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.2pt}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{7.1pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{7.1pt}}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{7.1pt}{7.1pt}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,>=latex,->]

\draw[thin] (-3,-1)  -- (-3,-2) node[below]{$w$};
\draw[thin] ( 4.8,1.075) -- (5.5,1.075) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[pattern=north east lines] (-3.3,-.5) rectangle (-2.7,-.65);
\draw[pattern=north east lines] ( 3.3,-.5) rectangle ( 2.7,-.65);
\draw(-3.2,-.5) -- (-2.8,-.5) -- (-3,-.2) -- cycle;
\draw( 3.2,-.5) -- ( 2.8,-.5) -- ( 3,-.2) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=white,draw=black] ( 3,-.2)  circle (.1cm);
\draw[fill=white,draw=black] (-3,-.2)  circle (.1cm);


\draw[pattern=north east lines] (-3.3,.6) rectangle (-2.7,.45);
\draw(-3,.9) -- (-3.2, .6) -- (-2.8,.6) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=white,draw=black] (-3,.9)  circle (.1cm);

\draw[pattern=north east lines] ( 3.3,.6) rectangle ( 2.7,.45);
\draw( 3,.9) -- ( 3.2, .6) -- ( 2.8,.6) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=white,draw=black] ( 3,.9)  circle (.1cm);



\draw[pattern=MYcrosshatch] (-3,1) rectangle (3,0);
\draw(-3,0) -- (-3,-.1) -- (3,-.1) -- (3,0) -- cycle;
\draw(-3,1) -- (-3, 1.15) -- (3, 1.15) -- (3,1) -- cycle;
\draw[-][very thin](-3,1.075) -- (3, 1.075);
\draw (-4,1.075)node[xshift=-8mm,left]{1} node[left]{$F_1$} -- (-3,1.075);
\draw (-4,-.05)node[xshift=-8mm,left]{2} node[left]{$F_2$} -- (-3,-.05);
\draw[<-] ( 3,-.05) -- (4,-.05) node[right]{$F_2$};
\draw[<-] ( 3,1.075) -- (4,1.075) node[right]{$F_1$};

\draw[-](-3,1) -- (-3,1.5);
\draw[-]( 3,1) -- ( 3,1.5);

\coordinate (p)   at (-3  ,1);
\coordinate (pa)  at ( 3  ,1.5);
\coordinate (p0)  at (-3  ,1.5);
\coordinate (p1)  at (-2.4,1.9);
\coordinate (p2)  at (-2.0,2.0);
\coordinate (p3)  at (-1.6,1.9);
\coordinate (p4)  at (-1.2,2.2);
\coordinate (p5)  at (-0.8,2.3);
\coordinate (p6)  at (-0.4,2.2);
\coordinate (p7)  at ( 0.0,2.4);
\coordinate (p8)  at ( 0.4,2.1);
\coordinate (p9)  at ( 0.8,2.2);
\coordinate (p10) at ( 1.2,2.3);
\coordinate (p11) at ( 1.6,2.5);
\coordinate (p12) at ( 2.0,2.0);
\coordinate (p13) at ( 2.4,2.1);


\draw (p1)  -- (-2.4,1.15);
\draw (p2)  -- (-2.0,1.15);
\draw (p3)  -- (-1.6,1.15);
\draw (p4)  -- (-1.2,1.15);
\draw (p5)  -- (-0.8,1.15);
\draw (p6)  -- (-0.4,1.15);
\draw (p7)  -- ( 0.0,1.15);
\draw (p8)  -- ( 0.4,1.15);
\draw (p9)  -- ( 0.8,1.15);
\draw (p10) -- ( 1.2,1.15);
\draw (p11) -- ( 1.6,1.15);
\draw (p12) -- ( 2.0,1.15);
\draw (p13) -- ( 2.4,1.15);


 \draw[smooth,-] plot coordinates{(p0)(p1)(p2)(p3)(p4)(p5)(p6)(p7)(p8)(p9)(p10)(p11)(p12)(p13)(pa)};
\node at (0,2.8){$f_1$};
\node at (0,0.5){K};
\node at (0,-0.5){$l$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Plus one for the effort, but from a structural point of view, that will break. There are *non-locating bearings* missing. (No idea if that is the correct english term)

Comment: @Johannes_B, I assure you I will not walk on that thing. I'm an electrical engineer. (:-). Hopefully, no innocent will get harmed.