# Curved torsional springs and dampers in TikZ mechanical system drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw some curved torsional springs and curved dampers in a mechanical system drawing. There are a number of questions on this site which deal with how to draw spring and damper components (see, for example, [Drawing Mechanical Systems in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13933/drawing-mechanical-systems-in-latex)), however, these all deal with springs and dampers which are not curved.

Specifically, I am trying to replicate this diagram:

[image]
Here's what I've got so far:

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzstyle{interface}=[postaction={draw,decorate,decoration={border,angle=-30,amplitude=0.1cm,segment length=0.6mm}}]
\tikzstyle{interfaceflipped}=[postaction={draw,decorate,decoration={border,angle=30,amplitude=0.1cm,segment length=0.6mm}}]

\newcommand\beamL{5cm}
\newcommand\beamH{0.1cm}
\newcommand\massL{0.5cm}
\newcommand\massH{0.5cm}

\draw (0,0)--++(0,-\beamH)--++(\beamL,0)--++(0,2*\beamH)--++(-\beamL,0)--cycle;
\draw (0,0)--++(0,-\massH)--++(-\massL,0)--++(0,2*\massH)--++(\massL,0)--cycle;
\draw [xshift=\beamL+\massL] (0,0)--++(0,-\massH)--++(-\massL,0)--++(0,2*\massH)--++(\massL,0)--cycle;

\coordinate (G1) at (5.5,-1); % Coordinates of ground 1
\path (G1) +(150:0.2) coordinate (G1start);
\draw [interface] (G1start)--++(-30:0.4);
\draw plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates {(\beamL,\beamH) ([yshift = 0.5cm,xshift = -0.08cm]\beamL,\beamH) ([yshift = 0.8cm]\beamL+\massL,\beamH) ([yshift = 1.1cm,xshift = 0.5cm]G1) (G1)};

\coordinate (G2) at (6.1,-1); % Coordinates of ground 2
\path (G2) +(150:0.2) coordinate (G2start);
\draw [interface] (G2start)--++(-30:0.4);
\draw plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates {(\beamL-0.2cm,\beamH) ([yshift = 0.8cm,xshift = -0.08cm]\beamL-0.2cm,\beamH) ([yshift = 1.3cm]\beamL+\massL,\beamH) ([yshift = 1.3cm,xshift = 0.5cm]G2) (G2)};

\begin{scope}[xshift=\beamL,xscale=-1]
\coordinate (G3) at (5.5,-1); % Coordinates of ground 3
\path (G3) +(150:0.2) coordinate (G3start);
\draw [interfaceflipped] (G3start)--++(-30:0.4);
\draw plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates {(\beamL,\beamH) ([yshift = 0.5cm,xshift = -0.08cm]\beamL,\beamH) ([yshift = 0.8cm]\beamL+\massL,\beamH) ([yshift = 1.1cm,xshift = 0.5cm]G3) (G3)};

\coordinate (G4) at (6.1,-1); % Coordinates of ground 4
\path (G4) +(150:0.2) coordinate (G4start);
\draw [interfaceflipped] (G4start)--++(-30:0.4);
\draw plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates {(\beamL-0.2cm,\beamH) ([yshift = 0.8cm,xshift = -0.08cm]\beamL-0.2cm,\beamH) ([yshift = 1.3cm]\beamL+\massL,\beamH) ([yshift = 1.3cm,xshift = 0.5cm]G4) (G4)};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With all respect, that's a horrific diagram. That's not even a torsional spring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good news is that Ti*k*Z has these coils in `decorations.pathmorphing`. The bad news is that one can get easily get `dimension too large` errors with that *if one uses `plot[smooth]`*. <s>One way to go is to scale the picture up such that these errors don't show, create a pdf and scale it down.</s> On the other hand, if one uses just the `to` syntax, this scaling is not needed. This is smooth as well as long `in` and the subsequent `out` differ by `180`. (Another neat side-effect of switching to this syntax is that it is slightly more straightforward to add labels.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{interface/.style={postaction={draw,decorate,decoration={border,angle=-30,amplitude=0.1cm,segment
length=0.6mm}}},
interfaceflipped/.style={postaction={draw,decorate,decoration={border,angle=30,amplitude=0.1cm,segment
length=0.6mm}}},
mycoil/.style={decorate,decoration={coil,segment
length=6pt,aspect=0.6,amplitude=5pt,post length=1mm,pre length=4mm}}}

\newcommand\beamL{5cm}
\newcommand\beamH{0.1cm}
\newcommand\massL{0.5cm}
\newcommand\massH{0.5cm}

\node[draw,minimum height={2*\massH},anchor=east,font=\small,inner sep=1pt] (I1)
at (0,0) {$I_{01}$};
\node[draw,minimum height={2*\massH},anchor=west,font=\small,inner sep=1pt] (I2)
at (\beamL,0) {$I_{02}$};
\draw ([yshift=\beamH]I1.east) -- ([yshift=\beamH]I2.west)
([yshift=-\beamH]I1.east) -- ([yshift=-\beamH]I2.west);

\coordinate (G1) at (5.5,-1); % Coordinates of ground 1
\path (G1) +(150:0.2) coordinate (G1start);
\draw [interface] (G1start)--++(-30:0.4);
\draw[-{Bar},shorten >=-2pt] (\beamL,\beamH) to[out=100,in=-120] 
([yshift = 0.5cm,xshift = -0.08cm]\beamL,\beamH) to[out=60,in=-180] 
([yshift=0.8cm]\beamL+\massL,\beamH) to[out=0,in=80]
([yshift = 1.1cm,xshift = 0.5cm]G1) node[above left,font=\small,xshift=1pt]{$c_{t2}$};

\draw[{Tee Barb[width=10pt,length=5pt,inset'={-4.5pt}]}-,shorten <=-3pt] 
([yshift = 1.1cm,xshift = 0.5cm]G1) to[out=-100,in=70] 
(G1);

\coordinate (G2) at (6.1,-1); % Coordinates of ground 2
\path (G2) +(150:0.2) coordinate (G2start);
\draw [interface] (G2start)--++(-30:0.4);
\draw[mycoil] (\beamL-0.2cm,\beamH) to[out=110,in=-110]
([yshift = 0.8cm,xshift = -0.08cm]\beamL-0.2cm,\beamH) to[out=70,in=180]  
([yshift = 1.3cm]\beamL+\massL,\beamH) to[out=0,in=80]
([yshift = 1.3cm,xshift = 0.5cm]G2) node[above right=0.4cm]{$k_{t2}$} to[out=-100,in=70]
(G2);

\begin{scope}[xshift=\beamL,xscale=-1]
\coordinate (G3) at (5.5,-1); % Coordinates of ground 3
\path (G3) +(150:0.2) coordinate (G3start);
\draw [interfaceflipped] (G3start)--++(-30:0.4);
\draw[-{Bar},shorten >=-2pt] (\beamL,\beamH) to[out=100,in=-120] 
([yshift = 0.5cm,xshift = -0.08cm]\beamL,\beamH) to[out=60,in=-180] 
([yshift = 0.8cm]\beamL+\massL,\beamH) to[out=0,in=80] 
 ([yshift = 1.1cm,xshift = 0.5cm]G3) node[above right,font=\small,xshift=-1pt]{$c_{t1}$};
\draw[{Tee Barb[width=10pt,length=5pt,inset'={-4.5pt}]}-,shorten <=-3pt] ([yshift = 1.1cm,xshift = 0.5cm]G3)
 to[out=-100,in=70]  (G3);

\coordinate (G4) at (6.1,-1); % Coordinates of ground 4
\path (G4) +(150:0.2) coordinate (G4start);
\draw [interfaceflipped] (G4start)--++(-30:0.4);
\draw[mycoil] (\beamL-0.2cm,\beamH) to[out=110,in=-110] 
([yshift = 0.8cm,xshift = -0.08cm]\beamL-0.2cm,\beamH) to[out=70,in=180]  
([yshift = 1.3cm]\beamL+\massL,\beamH)  to[out=0,in=80]  
([yshift = 1.3cm,xshift = 0.5cm]G4) node[above left=0.4cm]{$k_{t1}$} to[out=-100,in=70] (G4);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Added dampers using `arrows.meta`, simplified the code and also introduced `pre length` and `post length` to make the springs more "realistic".

Comment: +1 Thanks! Any ideas for how I could go about drawing the dampers?

Comment: @Milo Yes, I do. Please se my update.  (You can of course play with the dimensions like `width`, `length`, `inset` and `shorten`.)