# Drawing mechanical systems (Mass-Damper-spring) in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-styles

I don’t find any library that contain mechanical symbols. 
Could you help me to draw this diagram (mechanical system) in LaTeX?

[image: damped spring mass system]

Comment: Circuitikz has all three, although the mass is represented as a bipole (mass and ground in one).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Arguably even more basic than circuitikz would be to use just the `patterns` and `decorations.pathmorphing` libraries.

Comment: Thank you so much.
I am a beginner in LaTeX.
Could you help me to generate this graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give you a start. Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13952/121799).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={outer sep=0pt},thick,
 mass/.style={draw,thick},
 spring/.style={thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post
 length=0.3cm,segment length=6}},
 ground/.style={fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum
 width=0.75cm,minimum height=0.3cm},
 dampic/.pic={\fill[white] (-0.1,-0.3) rectangle (0.3,0.3);
 \draw (-0.3,0.3) -| (0.3,-0.3) -- (-0.3,-0.3);
 \draw[line width=1mm] (-0.1,-0.3) -- (-0.1,0.3);}]

  \node[mass,minimum width=3.5cm,minimum height=2cm,fill=green!50!black] (m1) {$m_1$};
  \node[mass,minimum width=3.5cm,minimum height=2cm,fill=green!50!black,right=1.5cm of
  m1] (m2) {$m_2$};
  \node[mass,minimum width=2.8cm,minimum height=1.5cm,fill=red!70,right=1.5cm of
  m2] (ma) {$m_a$};
  \node[left=2cm of m1,ground,minimum width=3mm,minimum height=2.5cm] (g1){};
  \draw (g1.north east) -- (g1.south east);

  \draw[spring] ([yshift=3mm]g1.east) coordinate(aux)
   -- (m1.west|-aux) node[midway,above=1mm]{$k_1$};
  \draw[spring]  (m1.east|-aux) -- (m2.west|-aux) node[midway,above=1mm]{$k_2$};
  \draw[spring]  (m2.east|-aux) -- (ma.west|-aux) node[midway,above=1mm]{$k_a$};

  \draw ([yshift=-3mm]g1.east) coordinate(aux')
   -- (m1.west|-aux') pic[midway]{dampic} node[midway,below=3mm]{$c_1$}
     (m1.east|-aux') -- (m2.west|-aux') pic[midway]{dampic} node[midway,below=3mm]{$c_2$}
     (m2.east|-aux') -- (ma.west|-aux') pic[midway]{dampic} node[midway,below=3mm]{$c_a$};

  \foreach \X in {1,2}  
  {\draw[thin] (m\X.north) -- ++ (0,1) coordinate[midway](aux\X);
   \draw[latex-] (aux\X) -- ++ (-0.5,0) node[above]{$F_\X$}; 
   \draw[thin,dashed] (m\X.south) -- ++ (0,-1) coordinate[pos=0.85](aux'\X);
   \draw[latex-] (aux'\X) -- ++ (-1,0) node[midway,above]{$x_\X$}
    node[left,ground,minimum height=7mm,minimum width=1mm] (g'\X){};
   \draw[thick] (g'\X.north east) -- (g'\X.south east);
  }

  \draw[thin,dashed] (ma.south) -- ++(0,-1.2);
  \draw[latex-] (ma.south |- aux'1) -- ++ (-1.5,0) coordinate(aux3)
  node[midway,above]{$x_d$};
  \draw[thin] ([yshift=-2mm]aux3) |- ++ (-1,0.5) -| (m2.-40);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much @marmot . 

 I will be very grateful if you give me some advice or sources for learning LaTeX tracing tools.

Comment: @E.Elmostafa You're welcome! The pgfmanual is very well written. Another strategy is to look at explicit examples and to try to understand them by looking the commands up in the pgfmanual.