# Drawing a mass-spring-dashpot system

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

[image]

With `circuitikz` package I can create circuits like the RLC circuit on the left in the figure above. Is there a similar library for mechanical oscillations systems as the mass-spring-dashpot system on the right? Thank you very much.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476076/drawing-mechanical-systems-mass-damper-spring-in-latex and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13933/drawing-mechanical-systems-in-latex/13952#13952

Comment: You can also have a look here: https://tikz.net/dynamics_spring

Comment: There is a parent page: https://latexdraw.com/category/physics/ with tutorials using Tikz in physiscs and a subpage: https://latexdraw.com/spring-mass-system-tikz/  with a tutorial for drawing a simple spring mass system in LaTeX, it's for vertical springs but with some modification you may create the horizontal case.

Comment: Creating a mass with wheels is not that difficult.  Circuitikz is TikZ with a bunch of added shapes.