# How to add angled tick marks to a path, illustrating a solid wall

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to use tikz to draw a line with hatch marks/angled ticks to illustrate a solid wall (as shown in the image). This seems like it would be useful feature that would have a solution. I have tried searching the decorations library to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13952/151808)

Comment: Yes, rather than decorating a path, filling a rectangle with a pattern with lines is a good solution. However for some reason the lines look patchy. In the viewer in Overleaf the lines appear dashed and when I download the pdf, the lines look continous but jagged. Any ideas for why this is, and how to make them look smoooth?

Comment: @DiggingDeep -- Your objection sounds reasonable.  Please add it to the question (referring to the proposed answer and describing the deficiency).  That way it's more likely to be noticed.