# Primitives of multibody mechanical systems with additional explanations

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, vector, physics, engineering

I need to draw the following pictures:

[image]
[image]

I tried to learn how to draw the necessary elements, focusing on the approach from this topic, because. I have never drawn such complex things in LaTeX before: [Drawing Mechanical Systems in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13933/drawing-mechanical-systems-in-latex/22326#22326)

I am not aware of the libraries that are required for such drawings. The code should be kept as simple as possible. Please, teach me the basics and I'll try to draw the rest myself. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please always show what you tried, because it is much easier to help you then. The right picture is actually not that hard to reproduce, since it is rather schematic.

Answer (score 4):

Well, 3D representations of mechanical parts are probably not the strength of Ti*k*Z. Such things are much easier to draw using CAD software, I assume. Maybe the following may serve as a starting point:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]

\draw[->] (0:0) node[above left] {$O$} -- (0:1);
\draw[->] (90:0) -- (90:1);
\draw[->] (225:0) -- (225:1);

\draw[->] (-45:0) -- (-45:5) node[below] {$W_i$};
\draw[->, dashed] (-60:0) -- (-60:5) node[below] {$W^\prime_i$};

\begin{scope}[shift={(-60:3.5)}, rotate=120]
    \fill[white] (0,0.3) -- +(0.5,0) 
        arc[start angle=90, end angle=-90, x radius=0.15, y radius=0.3] 
        -- (0,-0.3) -- (0,-0.2)
        arc[start angle=-90, end angle=90, x radius=0.1, y radius=0.2]
        --(0,0.3) -- cycle;
    \draw (0,0) circle[x radius=0.1, y radius=0.2];
    \draw (0,0) circle[x radius=0.15, y radius=0.3];
    \draw (0,0.3) -- +(0.5,0) arc[start angle=90, end angle=-90, x radius=0.15, y radius=0.3] -- (0,-0.3);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(20:3.5)}, rotate=210]
    \draw (0,0) circle[x radius=0.1, y radius=0.2];
    \draw (0,0) circle[x radius=0.15, y radius=0.3];
    \draw (0,0.3) -- +(0.5,0) arc[start angle=90, end angle=-90, x radius=0.15, y radius=0.3] -- (0,-0.3);
\end{scope}

\draw[fill=white] (-55:3) arc[start angle=-55, end angle=15, radius=3]
    to[in=95, out=95] (15:3.35)
    arc[start angle=15, end angle=-55, radius=3.35]
    to[in=-145, out=-145] (-55:3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]